# Highcharts: how to make y-axis labels CSS sticky?

Tags: css, highcharts, label

I have a long data grid that is a combination of a normal html data grid (table) and highcharts horizontal bar charts (1 per row).  The TH elements in the table grid are position sticky, and I want the corresponding y-axis labels to have the same behavior.  Basically when the user scrolls the table the highcharts y-axis labels scroll up and then "pin" to the top of the view, with teh data grid rows scrolling beneath it.

I can't figure out how to control the y-axis labels to force them to obey position sticky... probably because they're rendering in SVG.  Is this possible?  Is there a way to replicate the concept of position sticky for highcharts axis labels?

Comment: Hi @Rick Tilghman, Could you reproduce that problem in some minimal live example on jsfiddle?